# What is the meaning of grave accent (AKA backtick) quoted characters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering why some tutorials and other MySQL management tools use **grave accent** (`) in their queries like this one below:

```
SELECT `TableA`.`FieldA`, `TableA`.`FieldB`, `TableA`.`FieldC` 
FROM `Databasename`.`TableA`
```

When it displays the same result with this query below:

```
SELECT FieldA, FieldB, FieldC
FROM TableA
```

Comment: It's not an accent of any kind, it is a character glyph of its own.

Comment: @EJP exactly, a character called «grave accent» http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The grave is more commonly referred to as a "backtick", which MySQL uses to escape [MySQL reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

Wrapping everything in backticks is very common in PHPMyAdmin and various examples because most would rather name tables and columns whatever they like without worrying about naming errors.  I don't agree with the practice personally...

Comment: Hi, let's say i have dynamic column name in an sql query .. like SET $key='$value' etc ... that way I always need to backtick the $key variable right ? SET `$key`='$value' ...

Comment: @UnLoCo: As long as the MySQL variable name is a reserved word, yes - it'll need a backtick.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Also if the column name has a space for example ... AS `Customer Name`.

Comment: "The grave is more commonly referred to as a "backtick"" Citation needed.