# Copy values from one column to another in the same table

Tags: mysql, database

How can I make a copy values from one column to another?

I have:

```
Database name: list

-------------------
number | test
-------------------
123456 | somedata
123486 | somedata1
232344 | 34
```

I want to have:

```
Database name: list

----------------
number | test
----------------
123456 | 123456
123486 | 123486
232344 | 232344
```

What MySQL query should I have?

Answer (score 456, accepted):

Short answer for the code in question is:

```
UPDATE `table` SET test=number
```

Here `table` is the table name and it's surrounded by grave accent (aka back-ticks `) as this is MySQL convention to [escape keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857278/what-is-the-meaning-of-grave-accent-aka-backtick-quoted-characters-in-mysql) (and `TABLE` is a keyword in that case).

---

## BEWARE!

This is pretty dangerous query which will **wipe everything** in column `test` in every row of your table replacing it by the `number` (regardless of it's value)

It is more common to use `WHERE` clause to limit your query to only specific set of rows:

```
UPDATE `products` SET `in_stock` = true WHERE `supplier_id` = 10
```

Comment: It's one of those rare occasions where developers have thought like laymen.

Comment: Careful if you are unfamiliar with the `update command`... Without a **WHERE** clause, this command will `update` **ALL** records in the table.

Comment: Serious potential for wiping a lot of data, as @gmo cautioned. Consider making a backup of the database first, then run the query with a WHERE clause to limit it to one line. If you are happy with the result, remove the WHERE clause.

Comment: You may backup you table be fore the update action :)

Answer (score 36):

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `test` = `number`
```

You can also do any mathematical changes in the process or use MySQL functions to modify the values.

Answer (score 14):

try this:

```
update `list`
set `test` = `number`
```

Comment: list is <table name>

Answer (score 10):

**BEWARE** : Order of update columns is critical

**GOOD**: What I want saves existing Value of Status to PrevStatus

```
UPDATE Collections SET  PrevStatus=Status, Status=44 WHERE ID=1487496;
```

**BAD**: Status & PrevStatus both end up as 44

```
UPDATE Collections SET  Status=44, PrevStatus=Status WHERE ID=1487496;
```

Comment: Why are you setting Status=44, though?

Comment: @sceletia just an arbitrary value to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 9):

try following:

```
UPDATE `list` SET `test` = `number`
```

If `list` is table name and `test` and `number` are columns

it creates copy of all values from "number" and paste it to "test"

Answer (score 6):

Following worked for me..

1. Ensure you are not using Safe-mode in your query editor application. If you are, disable it!
2. Then run following sql command

> for a table say, 'test_update_cmd', source value column col2, target
>   value column col1 and condition column col3: -
>
> ```
> UPDATE  test_update_cmd SET col1=col2 WHERE col3='value';
> ```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

IF Anyone wants to put Condition

UPDATE `bohf` SET `Sq`=`IDNo` WHERE `Table` = 'AOF' AND `FormSq` BETWEEN 13 AND 17

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -8):

```
update `table`
set `firstcolumn` = `secondcolumn`
```