# Update and Select at the same time on the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to copy what is inside on the column `name` on the other column `property_title` on the same table `propertylistings`

```
===============================
name         | property_title |
===============================
house        |                |
condominium  |                |
room         |                |
===============================
```

this is my query but it is not working

```
UPDATE proplistings property_title SET (SELECT name FROM proplistings)
```

Comment: It should be as simple as `UPDATE proplistings SET property_title = name`

Comment: check out the mysql UPDATE syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy values from one column to another in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001939/copy-values-from-one-column-to-another-in-the-same-table)

Comment: @Scuzzy, didn't notice your comment. Thumbs up for a speedy one :)

Comment: @Samir You've got the right answer anyway, I hope your one gets accepted

Answer (score 7):

Just as simple as this. No need for any subquery.

```
UPDATE proplistings SET property_title = name;
```