# MySQL 5.1 - I want to duplicate data from joined column

Tags: mysql, join, duplicates

I'm trying to copy columns of data from 2 joined tables in different schemas.

I've joined and happy with the result - but get errors when I try to use code that I've found on here to copy the data.

I'm using MySQL 5.1 and can not upgrade.

I need to copy the values from ampp.vppid (t2?) directly over to medicament.CODE3 (t1?)

I have tried the following:

```
select * from mls.medicament t1 join dmd.ampp t2 on t2.APPID = t1.code1
set t1.CODE3 = t2.VPPID;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001939/copy-values-from-one-column-to-another-in-the-same-table you can have a look over this, this will help you

Comment: Thanks, I came across this one during my search. The problem I have is because the tables are joined - I can not seem to get the basic commands to work. I also think my version of MySQL (5.1) is restricting my efforts.

Comment: No - sorry but your answer does not specifically solve my problem - specifically it does not mention how to accomplish this with joined tables.

Answer (score 0):

[Copy values from one column to another in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001939/copy-values-from-one-column-to-another-in-the-same-table)

you can have a look over this, this will help you and let you solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may be interested - using update with an inner join worked.

I moved the table I was referencing into the same Schema to keep it simple - as it didn't need its own Schema.

```
update mls.medicament A inner join mls.amp B on A.CODE1 = B.APID set A.CODE3=B.vpid;
```