# Alterning a table that has spaces in its name

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add 3 columns. There are two things that I dont know, one is how to specify a default value for each column, and then next is how to alter a table that has got spaces:

```
    ALTER TABLE  app name and url
ADD COLUMN price VARCHAR(200)
ADD COLUMN type_of_membership VARCHAR(200)
ADD COLUMN special_deal VARCHAR(200)
```

I get this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'name and url ADD COLUMN price VARCHAR(200) ADD COLUMN type_of_membership VARCH' at line 1

I guess it is because I have a tables name with spaces.

Is this how you insert default values:

```
    ALTER TABLE  app name and url
ADD COLUMN price VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT 'None'
ADD COLUMN type_of_membership VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT 'None'
ADD COLUMN special_deal VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT 'None'
```

**UPDATE** 
This is what I executed:

```
ALTER TABLE  `app name and url`
ADD COLUMN price VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT 'None',
ADD COLUMN type_of_membership VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT 'None',
ADD COLUMN special_deal VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT 'None';
```

and this is what I got:

```
 'mydb.app name and url' is not BASE TABLE
```

The error is because it is a view..I get it now. I will have to modify the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ``` `` ```

You have to replace the table name with

```
 ALTER TABLE  `app name and url`
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be7a0/1)

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd: `app name and url` is a view or a table?

Answer (score 3):

In Mysql, you need to escape it using `backtick` (*grave accent*)

```
ALTER TABLE  `app name and url`
ADD COLUMN price VARCHAR(200)
ADD COLUMN type_of_membership VARCHAR(200)
ADD COLUMN special_deal VARCHAR(200)
```

[What is the meaning of grave accent (AKA backtick) quoted characters in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857278/what-is-the-meaning-of-grave-accent-aka-backtick-quoted-characters-in-mysql)

**PS:** Next time use only alphanumeric in your table and column name.

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd if some other table has reference to the table you want to alter, it won't. otherwise it will..

Comment: I get this error: mytable  is not BASE TABLE error 1347 . what does that mean

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd be sure that it is not a view.